# How to process files with same name in Apache NiFi?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi

I'm learning NiFi and I'm working on a flow where I get files using `GetFile` and then I do some process and then store them into HDFS using `PutHDFS` processor. The thing is, most probably I'll get files with the same name. For ex, I might get a file every 30 minutes and the file that is generated every 30 minutes will have the same name.

Now when I put that file into HDFS, I get an "File with the same name already exists". How do I overcome this? Is there any way to change the file name on the run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a very easy one. I just have to use `UpdateAttribute` processor to change the file name. For ex: you can append `timestamp` to the file name.

In the `UpdateProcessor`, add a property `filename` and its value `${filename}.${now()}`

Comment: Just in case of high rates where timestamps may also have collisions, expression language also has a UUID function https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#uuid

Comment: When I set this value I get an error "Unable to evaluate new value for attribute 'filename'

Comment: Got it, please correct above value from ${filename}.${now} to ${filename}.${now()}